# Что лучше использовать WorkManager или Service?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Прочитал, что `WorkManager` включает в себя сервисы + всякие плюшки. Или есть какие-то моменты где `Service` лучше (т.к. его ограничили сильно)?

Answer (score 3):

Ну начнем с того, что это разные инструменты, которые выполняют разные задачи.

> Cервис – это некая задача, которая работает в фоне и не использует UI.
> Запускать и останавливать сервис можно из приложений и других
> сервисов. Также можно подключиться к уже работающему сервису и
> взаимодействовать с ним.

- Сервисы нужны для того, чтоб выполнять длительные операции в фоне (например: загрузка файлов, проигрывание музыки или навигатор в фон). Сервис позволяет выполнять какой-то функционал без явного запуска приложения или при свернутом приложении.

> WorkManager позволяет запускать фоновые задачи последовательно или параллельно,
> передавать в них данные, получать из них результат, отслеживать статус
> выполнения и запускать только при соблюдении заданных условий.

- WorkManager хоть и содержит в себе сервисы, но это о другом. WorkManager это инструмент для планировки задач (например мы можете хотеть каждое утро проверять актуальность неких данных, используемых в вашем приложении).

Поэтому вопрос, что лучше, тут не уместен. Это разные инструменты которые используются для совершенно разных задач. Хотя тот же WorkManager в итоге может запустить сервис который будет уже работать как описано выше.